# PHP Undefined variable

Tags: php, intelephense

When I test an easy PHP program , I found that there is a strange problem.
The code is in fllow:

```
<?php

$a = "abc";
function Test()
{
    global $a;
    $b .= $a."e";
    return $b;
}

echo Test();
```

As I know,it is legal.But Visual Studio Code tells me that the $b is Undefined variable.
[image]

At the same time, the program can run successfully with the output:`abce`

[image]

Anybody can help me? I want to know the reason.

Comment: You need to look closer to the `.=` operator you are using. It explains, why you're getting a Warning. And no, it is nowhere legal. Neither using .= or global. it must be function Test($a) instead of using global

Comment: Another reason why code needs to be indented properly(if you were already aware of `.=`)

Comment: @YourCommonSense What's illegal about using `global` like that?

Comment: There are 2 ways to do it, first, don't use global because it's not make any sense you can just use string and passed into a variable. But if you want to use global then don't append just use $b = "ABC";

Answer (score -1):

It's because you used `.=` instead of just `=`. That means the RHS gets appended to the LHS, which means it's expected to have been set before. If you didn't expect `$b` to exist before, then you should have just used `=`.